# Tkinter checkbox background toggle

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to get it so when the checkbox Is toggled on it will change the background to a white (#00ffdd) and when toggled off it will turn back to the dark colour (#393636). Thanks.

tried making it a command but did not work.

```
from tkinter import *


#At the end of this all open slides have to be x.destroy()
#this removes them till wanted again
#eg settings.destroy inventory.destroy


def helpmenu():
    #85 > 21 ^
    help1 = Label(unbox, text ="How to play:",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10 bold")
    help2 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help3 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help4 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help5 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help6 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help7 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help8 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help9 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help10 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help11 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help12 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help13 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help14 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help15 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help16 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help17 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help18 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help19 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help20 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help21 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")
    help22 = Label(unbox, text ="####################################################################################~",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10")


    help1.place(x=0, y=30)
    help2.place(x=0, y=50)
    help3.place(x=0, y=70)
    help4.place(x=0, y=90)
    help5.place(x=0, y=110)
    help6.place(x=0, y=130)
    help7.place(x=0, y=150)
    help8.place(x=0, y=170)
    help9.place(x=0, y=190)
    help10.place(x=0, y=210)
    help11.place(x=0, y=230)
    help12.place(x=0, y=250)
    help13.place(x=0, y=270)
    help14.place(x=0, y=290)
    help15.place(x=0, y=310)
    help16.place(x=0, y=330)
    help17.place(x=0, y=350)
    help18.place(x=0, y=370)
    help19.place(x=0, y=390)
    help20.place(x=0, y=410)
    help21.place(x=0, y=430)
    help22.place(x=0, y=450)

def settings ():
    setting1 = Checkbutton(unbox, text ="oof mode",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10", command = unbox.configure(background="#00ffdd"))
    setting1.place(x=0, y=100)




#####################################################################################################################
unbox = Tk()
unbox.geometry ("600x480")
unbox.configure(background="#393636")
unbox.title("Dunno What Game This Is:")
unbox.resizable(0,0)

button = Button(unbox, text = "  Close:   ",fg = "#af0519", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10", command = exit)
button.place(x=0, y=1)

button1 = Button(unbox, text = "     Inventory:     ",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10", command = print ("test"))
button1.place(x=65, y=1)

button2 = Button(unbox, text = "       Market:      ",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10", command = print ("test"))
button2.place(x=168, y=1)

button3 = Button(unbox, text = "      Gambling:     ",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10", command = print ("test"))
button3.place(x=272, y=1)

button4 = Button(unbox, text = "      Settings:     ",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10", command = settings)
button4.place(x=386, y=1)

button5 = Button(unbox, text = "    Help Menu:      ",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10", command = helpmenu)
button5.place(x=493, y=1)





mainloop()
```

Should change background colour when checked and change it back when unchecked. Actually changes the background permanently. Thanks.

Comment: Checkbox is setting1

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with a checkbutton, we probably don't need 22 labels plus six other buttons to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, try to define your GUI as a class. It will ease accessing some variables and will make code more readable.

To solve your problem, You must introduce variable that will store state of the checkbox, so You can check which color should be applied. Something like this should work:

```
def settings ():
    def setting1_checked(widget):
        if var.get():
            widget.configure(background="#00ffdd")
        else:
            widget.configure(background="#363636")

    var = IntVar()
    setting1 = Checkbutton(unbox, text ="oof mode",fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#363636", font = "Helvetica 10", command = lambda: setting1_checked(setting1), variable=var)
    setting1.place(x=0, y=100)
```

Comment: Thanks :). However this changes the checkbox background. I Think I could figure it out however. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hm... I assumed after `it will change the background to a white` that it relates to checkbox, not to window.

Comment: Hm alright, strange. Yea I wanted it to change the window background but I'm still not sure.